# How to manage sorting of Wrap widget?

Tags: flutter

I have a, b, and c widgets.
These widgets have the same width as 100.
I wrap these widgets with the `Wrap` widget like

```
Wrap(children: [a, b, c])
```

In general, when the screen width is 200, the UI will display these widgets like this.

```
a b
c
```

But I want

```
a b
  c
```

Is there an option in the `Wrap` widget to do this?

Comment: `alignment: WrapAlignment.end,` should do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `alignment` on your `Wrap` widget:

```dart
Wrap(
    alignment: WrapAlignment.end,
    children: [a, b, c],
)
```

[Dartpad example](https://dartpad.dev/?id=fb96b86b113eda6c9567165f1ce9365f)

[Wrap class documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html)